# Iterating through a linked-list in a cleaner manner

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I have a collection of `PlaylistItem` objects. They are linked together such that each item knows the ID of its next/previous item. I am iterating over this collection of objects, starting at a known position and working with each object once. I'm not a big fan of how I do this, but I am not seeing an obvious way of rewriting it.

```
var firstItemId = activePlaylist.get('firstItemId');
var currentItem = activePlaylist.get('items').get(firstItemId);

//  Build up the ul of li's representing each playlistItem.
do {

    var listItem = $('<li/>', {
        'data-itemid': currentItem.get('id'),
        contextmenu: function (e) {

            var clickedItemId = $(this).data('itemid');
            var clickedItem = activePlaylist.get('items').get(clickedItemId);

            contextMenu.initialize(clickedItem);

            //  +1 offset because if contextmenu appears directly under mouse, hover css will be removed from element.
            contextMenu.show(e.pageY, e.pageX + 1);
            //  Prevent default context menu display.
            return false;
        }
    }).appendTo(playlistItemList);

    $('<img>', {
        'class': 'playlistItemVideoImage',
        src: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + currentItem.get('video').get('id') + '/default.jpg',
    }).appendTo(listItem);

    $('<a/>', {
        text: currentItem.get('title')
    }).appendTo(listItem);

    currentItem = activePlaylist.get('items').get(currentItem.get('nextItemId'));
} while (currentItem && currentItem.get('id') !== firstItemId)
```

How would you write this?

Note that it is a `do-while` because I want to ensure I always render that `firstItem`. If there's only one item in the list, the loop will immediately terminate. Thus the need for the `do-while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit of "light" refactoring. I've basically moved the element constructing into its own function to keep the while-block less crowded.

I'm also using some closure magic for the contextmenu, so it doesn't have to re-get the clicked item.

Lastly, I'm going more by the current *ID* rather than the current *object* when looping. This was to avoid the "get the id to get the object to get its id again" code that I see a few places in your version.

```
function buildListItem(item) {
  var listItem = $('<li/>', {
    contextmenu: function (event) {
      contextMenu.initialize(item); // available via closure
      contextMenu.show(e.pageY, e.pageX + 1);
      return false;
    }
  });

  listItem.append($('<img>', {
    'class': 'playlistItemVideoImage',
    'src':   'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + item.get('video').get('id') + '/default.jpg'
  }));

  listItem.append($('<a/>', {
    text: item.get('title')
  }));

  return listItem;
}

var firstItemId   = activePlaylist.get('firstItemId'),
    allItems      = activePlaylist.get('items'),
    currentItemId = firstItemId,
    currentItem;

do {
  currentItem = allItems.get(currentItemId);             // get the obj
  if(!currentItem) {
    break;                                               // stop if it ain't there
  }
  playlistItemList.append(buildListItem(currentItem));   // build the list item element
  currentItemId = currentItem.get('nextItemId');         // get the next ID
} while(currentItemId && currentItemId !== firstItemId); // I'm assuming that valid IDs are thruth'y
```

Another thing to consider would be to use rawer HTML [because it can be faster](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly).